# Iterating over lines in a file in Python

Tags: python

The file takes the format:

```
Britany     6.06 5.31 4.34 8.60 4.14 3.12 3.53 5.16
Eula        6.46 9.84 7.17 4.89 6.24 8.82 4.31 9.08
Georgianna  0.52 6.95 6.67 5.54 8.27 0.57 8.42 2.76
Emilee      2.66 5.73 3.29 1.27 2.66 9045 1.16 2.81
Serina      3.07 9.22 3.59 0.89 3.91 9.79 6.48 7.81
```

What I need to do is create a function that will check if each score for each contestant is between 0 and 10. If all scores of a contestant are acceptable, the contestant and his/her scores are written to the clean data file, if not, the contestant is eliminated and his/her data are not written to the clean data file. The names and scores of eliminated contestants should be stored in a list.

Here is my code so far:

```html
def cleanData(userIn,userOut):
    fileIn = open(userIn,'r',encoding = 'UTF8')
    fileOut = open(userOut,'w',encoding = 'UTF8')
    eliminated=[]
    for line in fileIn:
        tempList= line.rsplit(maxsplit=-9)
        for num in tempList:
            if num in range(0,11):
                userOut.write(line)
            else:
                eliminated.append(line)
```

What I am attempting to do is read the line in the file and split it into a list so I can iterate over the numbers. Then I am trying to check if each number meets the criteria for a valid score and if all the numbers meet this goal write that line to the output file. Otherwise I want to append the line to the empty list eliminated for later use. I am not sure if I am using maxsplit properly, but I believe that I am starting from the right most index of -1 and wan to finish at -8, which would create a list of only the numbers.

Comment: Did you try both ways and compare them? In the end, it doesn't matter which way you go as long as you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this. This iterates, line-by-line, splits the line by the white spaces, and then counts the number of floats after the name where 0 <= x <= 10:

```
outfile = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
for line in open('scores.txt', 'r').readlines():
    if len([score for score in line.strip().split()[1:] if (float(score) >= 0 and float(score) <= 10)]) == 8:
        outfile.write(line.strip() + '\n')

outfile.close()
```

It's expecting to see 8 floats. It doesn't handle spaces in the names, and will throw an error if it encounters something it can't convert to a float.

Comment: IMO, it's more elegant and concise if you do `input = open("scores.txt", "r")` `for line in input:`

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        process_line(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is an assignment, I'll offer you some hints:

1. Keep in mind that the data you are reading are strings, not numbers. So make sure you convert them appropriately before doing any math.
2. Use `.split()` to convert each line into a list.
3. Use the `with statement` to open the file and iterate over it, you can use it to read and write at the same time:

   ```
   with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as inf, open('otherfile.txt', 'w') as outf:
      for line in inf:
         # do something with the line
         if line matches some condition:
             outf.write(line)  # write the same line out
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, a functional programming solution:

```
def is_int_less_than_10(x):
    result = False
    try:
        result = float(x)<10
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return result


with open('in.txt', 'r') as f_in, open('out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        values = [x.strip() for x in line.split(" ")[1:] if x.strip()] #skip country and clean the values
        if all(map(is_int_less_than_10, values): 
            f_out.write(line)
```

Comment: Your method can be simplifed to `try: return float(x) < 10.0 except ValueError: pass`, and `f.out.write` should be `f_out.write`